# How do I write a neo4j query that only returns a node that doesn't have a very specific relationship with another kind of node

Tags: python, database, neo4j, cypher

Lets use a family tree for simplicity's sake.

(A: Person)<-[:parent_of]-(B: Human)<-[:parent_of]-(C: human)<-[:parent_of]<-(D: Human)

For the sake of arguing, node A is of a different type than nodes B, C, and D, it doesn't matter why.

I want to find a query to return only node A's if none of the "human" nodes connected to them have the property "social security number" (e.g. D.ssn = Null OR trim(D.ssn) = '')

If one of A's relatives has that property, I don't want it returned.

I've tried experimenting with lots of where clauses with parenthesis but neo4j didn't like it.

I also tried some pattern matching but apparently I was getting a cartesian product and couldn't figure out why. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
WHERE NOT (a)<-[:parent_of]-(:Human {ssn: x})
RETURN a
```

Comment: Couple of questions. What would I put where the x is in ssn: x? Since I'm looking to not match anything if its parent_of has ANYTHING in the ssn field other than null or empty, what goes there? Does x just mean "anything"? 

2, would this still work for an arbitrary relationship rather than a specific one? Because if you look above, its not just parent of, its parent of parent of parent... possibly forever. 

Would this work still?
match (a:Person)
where not (a)<-[*]-(:Human {ssn: x})
return a
?

Comment: So I just tried the following query:

match (a:Person)
where not (a)<-[*]-(:Human {ssn: not null}) 
return a

and several of the returned node had ancestors with that property not being null. 

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We can use WITH to pass the nodes b,c and d as a list to next part of the query. Then we can use all(x IN humans WHERE x.ssn IS NOT NULL) which returns true if the property ssn is not null for all elements in the list.

```
Match (a:Person)-[:parent_of]-(b: Human)<-[:parent_of]-(c: human)<-[:parent_of]<-(d: Human)
WITH [b, c, d]as humans, a as mainPerson
WHERE all(x IN humans WHERE x.ssn IS NOT NULL)
RETURN mainPerson
```